# JPQL query IS NOT NULL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I can't understand what can be wrong with following `JPQL` query:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("FROM FaPrimaryDocument AS t WHERE (t.debitAccount.id = :id or t.creditAccount.id = :id) " +
                "AND t.debitAccount IS NOT NULL AND t.creditAccount IS NOT NULL ");
Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString(), FaPrimaryDocument.class)
                .setParameter("id", id);

List<FaPrimaryDocument> transactions = q.getResultList();
```

[image]

Above query returns rows with `debitAccount/creditAccount = null`. How can I change it so that not to return rows with `debitAccount/creditAccount = null`

Comment: It looks like query is correct.

Comment: Wait a minute. I'll post output

Comment: @Milkmaid, post updated

Comment: To understand "what is wrong" why not look at the LOG and see the SQL that is actually issued??

Comment: @NeilStockton, the same query as above

Comment: WHAT same query as above? (there is no SQL posted) JPQL is one thing (and yours has omitted SELECT, incorrectly). SQL is a different thing.

Comment: @Sher Neil mean set in persistence to show you SQL query (Not JPQL) this setup is different per implementation. After you will see the real SQL  query then it will gives you better overview where should be the problem. But from my point of view the JPQL query looks correct. It should be adjusted: `SELECT t FROM FaPrimaryDocument t WHERE t.debitAccount IS NOT NULL AND t.creditAccount IS NOT NULL AND (t.debitAccount.id = :id or t.creditAccount.id = :id) `

Comment: I can't understand how looking at logs can help figure out the problem. Above is the simple query. It should or it shouldn't work, and there have to be some simple explaation

Comment: @NeilStockton : Is it portability issue or something else, when `SELECT` is excluded from JPQL? It should be optional while selecting all fields. (I am accustomed to writing criteria. Therefore, I am less concerned with JPQL than criteria).

Comment: @Tiny JPQL is defined by the JPA spec (as opposed to the Hibernate docs). "SELECT {alias}" is mandatory. That's all there is to say if you care about portability and sticking to standards.

Comment: @Sher ... the logs are created for you to debug your problem. The SQL would show whether the JPA implementation has created what you would expect. If you don't want to debug and blindly believe that the JPA implementation does all you think it should then .... good luck

Comment: @NeilStockton, I don't think that logs don't have any use. I mean, that in this context, query is quite simple, and there should be simple logical explanation of above query inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried some different methods. And here how it worked out:

```
"SELECT t " +
                "FROM FaPrimaryDocument AS t " +
                "JOIN t.debitAccount AS da " +
                "JOIN t.creditAccount AS ca " +
                "WHERE " +
                    "((da.id = :id) OR (ca.id = :id)) " ;
```